# How to create a stored procedure that uses a transaction?

Tags: transactions

I was able to create the stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 below, but now I have hit a brick wall because I need to do it in a way that the stored procedure will use a transaction and will check for errors on the insert statement. When the error is found - the transaction should roll back and nothing should be committed. Any help would be appreciated.

USE Northwind
GO
CREATE PROC spEmployee @EmployeeID int
AS
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EmployeeID=''+@EmployeeID+''
GO
EXEC spEmployee @EmployeeID=2
GO

---

CREATE PROC spEmployee @EmployeeID int

AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EmployeeID=''+@EmployeeID+''

GO
EXEC spEmployee @EmployeeID=2

GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0

BEGIN

ROLLBACK

RAISERROR ('Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.', 16, 2)

RETURN

END

COMMIT

Answer (score 0):

Firstly go read about the try catch block in SQL2005 upwards. You are using SQL 2000 error handling here. SQL books online will be very useful for the information you need.